# How to indent code in apex class created using tooling API

Tags: apex, tooling-api

I have below apex code to create a new apex class from a string using tooling api

```
apexBody = '{"Name": "myClass", "body": "public class myClass {@AuraEnabled public String NAME;@AuraEnabled public String POST;@AuraEnabled public Boolean MALE;@AuraEnabled public Integer AGE;}"}'

HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionID());
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
req.setMethod(method);
req.setBody(apexBody);
```

It successfully creates my class in the below format

[image]

But should be indented like below

[image]

Could someone please help me what can be done to add the indentation also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\r` and `\t` to format your code. You can also make your code easier to read with some proper JSON encoding:

```
public class ApexClassWrapper {
  public String Name;
  public String Body;
}

ApexClassWrapper myClass = new ApexClassWrapper();
myClass.Name='myClass';
myClass.Body='public class myClass{\n'+
    '\t@AuraEnabled public String NAME;\n'+
    '\t@AuraEnabled public String POST;\n'+
    '\t@AuraEnabled public Boolean MALE;\n'+
    '\t@AuraEnabled public Integer AGE;\n'+
    '}';
String jsonPayload = JSON.serialize(myClass);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are doing quite a bit of this sort of generation, best to break the code out into separate lines so the formatting is clearer:

```
String[] lines = new String[] {
    'public class myClass {',
    '    @AuraEnabled public String NAME;',
    '    @AuraEnabled public String POST;',
    ...
}
```

and then join the lines:

```
String text = String.join(lines, '\n');
```

and if you are going a lot of this sort of generation, write a builder class to make the indentation easier to achieve.

See sfdcfox's solution for the care needed on the JSON generation.

Comment: Close, but you forgot to JSON.serialize that string or double-up on the backslashes to escape them properly, so it would result in bad JSON.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, Cool I'll delete this in a minute.

Comment: Left the notion of joining in as it gets rid of the noisy formatting.

Comment: Nice. Using String.join also gives flexibility if you want to create variable parameters for some reason, etc.

Comment: Many thank you, this is certainly helpful.